# How do you cancel a PayPal subscription through their api?

Tags: paypal

On this page: [Handling Recurring Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments)

It says that it's possible to cancel a PayPal subscription using their API. Knowing the SubscriptionId can anyone give me some code example how to do this?

At the moment I do it manually which is a pain (I log into my PayPal account, find the subscription and cancel it).

I would like to automate this process basically.

Comment: Have you written any code yourself? If so you should post it here and what error message/problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I just can't see how it's possible to do it.

Answer (score 3):

In perl it could be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

# Set values for $paypal_api_user, $paypal_api_pwd and 
# $paypal_api_signature from your paypal's profile
my $paypal_api_user = '....';
my $paypal_api_pwd  = '.....';
my $paypal_api_signature = '.....';

# Set subscription id
my $subscr_id = '....';

my $params = {
  'USER' => $paypal_api_user,
  'PWD' => $paypal_api_pwd,
  'SIGNATURE' => $paypal_api_signature,
  'VERSION' => '84.0',
  'METHOD' => 'ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus',
  'PROFILEID' => $subscr_id,
  'ACTION' => 'Cancel',
};
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();

my $res = $ua->post('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp', $params);

if ($res->is_error()) {
  # HTTP error
} else {
  # Success
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the type of the subscription usually. If it starts with S-, it can't be modified though the API's. If it starts with I-, it can.

Have look at the [ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus) API for this.
This allows you to send an ACTION=Cancel, ACTION=Suspend or ACTION=Reactivate.

Comment: * Cancel new I-* Subscriptions using PayPals ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API.

* Cancel old S-* Subscriptions by using PhantomJS + this script: 
http://blog.degree.no/2015/10/cancelling-old-s-paypal-subscriptions-from-code/