# How to Set end date for paypal Recurring Payments With Direct Payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am using Recurring Payments With Direct Payment( https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments#id08669F0705Z )

I set parameter as below and WORKING FINE,

```
$firstName = urlencode('MyName');//urlencode('customer_first_name');
$lastName = urlencode('MySurname');//urlencode('customer_last_name');
$creditCardType = urlencode('VISA');//urlencode('customer_credit_card_type');
$creditCardNumber = urlencode('455743552XXXXXXXX');//urlencode('customer_credit_card_number');
$expDateMonth = '07';//'cc_expiration_month';
$expDateYear = urlencode('2017');//urlencode('cc_expiration_year');
$padDateMonth = urlencode(str_pad($expDateMonth, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
$amount =  urlencode('5');// urlencode('example_payment_amuont');
$startDate = urlencode("2012-07-17T0:0:0");
$endDate = urlencode("2012-07-21T0:0:0");

$billingPeriod = urlencode("Day");              // or "Day", "Week", "SemiMonth", "Year"
$billingFreq = urlencode("1");                      // combination of this and billingPeriod must be at most a year
$currencyID = urlencode("USD"); 

$nvpStr = "&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType".
          "&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
          "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear".
          "&FIRSTNAME=MyFirstName".
          "&LASTNAME=MyLastName".
          "&PROFILESTARTDATE=$startDate".
          "&PROFILEENDDATE=$endDate".     // **not working**
          "&BILLINGPERIOD=$billingPeriod".
          "&BILLINGFREQUENCY=$billingFreq".
          "&AMT=$amount&DESC=Test Recurring Payment";

$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $nvpStr);
```

Now my issue is end date not set, so please reply if anybody had idea.
***I want parameter for setting end date.***

Thankx,
Kiran Sharma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer,

its "**TOTALBILLINGCYCLES**" which will set the number of cycles to occure.

as above i use,
$billingPeriod = urlencode("Day");   // the cycle is per day
$billingFreq = urlencode("1");  // freq is 1. so, payment colledt every day

**"&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=15"  // now when i use this parameter the cycle takes place 15 times so payment collect 15 for 15 days.**